# Como seleciono varios valores da mesma tabela

Tags: php, pdo, select

Como faço para selecionar os valores 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5 de uma mesma tabela sem fazer aquele monte de SELECT ?

```
<?php
$rateone    = 1;
$ratetwo    = 2;
$ratethree  = 3;
$ratefour   = 4;
$ratefive   = 5;

$query = "SELECT COUNT(rate) as rate FROM tb_comment WHERE id_mark=:post_id AND rate=:rateone";

    $resultone = $conexao->prepare($query);
    $resultone->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $resultone->bindParam(':rateone', $rateone, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $resultone->execute();
    $count = $resultone->rowCount();

    if($count =1){
        $loop = $resultone->fetchAll();
        foreach ($loop as $show) {
            $Crateone = $show['rate'];
        }
    }

echo $Crateone;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quiser que cada `rate` venha em uma linha separada, isso basta:

```
SELECT      rate, COUNT(*) AS row_count
FROM        tb_comment
WHERE       id_mark=:post_id
GROUP BY    rate
```

Note que eu mudei o `AS rate` para `AS rate_sum`, e acrescentei o `rate` original no `SELECT`. Evite usar `AS` com nomes que já existem na tabela, para não confundir. Se precisar, pus exemplo do `COUNT()` também.

Se preferir pode acrescentar um `ORDER BY rate`, ou `ORDER BY rate DESC` para determinar a ordem da menor para a maior, ou o inverso.

Lembre-se de trocar o *loop* para pegar todas as linhas.

```
if($count > 0){
    $loop = $resultone->fetchAll();
    foreach ($loop as $show) {
        echo $show['rate'] . ' - ' . $show['row_count'];
    }
}
```

Pode simplificar também:

```
while ( $show = $resultone->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {;
   echo $show['rate'] . ' - ' . $show['row_count'];
}
```

Montando o código:

```
$query =
 'SELECT rate, COUNT(*) AS row_count FROM tb_comment WHERE id_mark=:post_id GROUP BY rate';

$resultone = $conexao->prepare($query);
$resultone->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultone->execute();

while ( $show = $resultone->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
   echo $show['rate'] . ' - ' . $show['row_count'] . "<br>\n";
}
```

E ainda, se quiser usar os resultados separadamente:

```
$query =
 'SELECT rate, COUNT(*) AS row_count FROM tb_comment WHERE id_mark=:post_id GROUP BY rate';

$resultone = $conexao->prepare($query);
$resultone->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultone->execute();

$ratings = array( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
while ( $show = $resultone->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
   $ratings[ (int) $show['rate'] ] = $show['row_count'];
}
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
     echo $i . ' - ' . $ratings[$i] . "<br>\n"; 
}
```

Comment: HAHA minha especialidade front-end *.* obrigado pela ajuda novamente!